# Capture matching text format in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to extract the items in the text below that start with the `#` and ends with `)`

`const bodyOfText = "#[DataStructures](topic_DataStructures) is one #[Algorithms](topic_Algorithms) branch that could #[Make or Mar](topic_Make or Mar)";`

So basically, will want an array that looks like:

`["#[DataStructures](topic_DataStructures)", "#[Algorithms](topic_Algorithms)", "#[Make or Mar](topic_Make or Mar)"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string `match()` we can try:

```js
var bodyOfText = "#[DataStructures](topic_DataStructures) is one #[Algorithms](topic_Algorithms) branch that could #[Make or Mar](topic_Make or Mar)";
var matches = bodyOfText.match(/#\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/g);
console.log(matches);
```